# Can I give the same name to a table and a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Is it possible to name a stored procedure the same as a table? I have an existing table named 'buyers', and I'm trying to create a stored procedure named 'buyers', but I'm getting this error:

> There is already an object named 'buyers' in the database.

Comment: `I'm creating a stored procedure named 'buyers'` -- I would strongly reconsider this name as it's not very descriptive. The need to duplicate names in this way is highly suspect.

Answer (score 10):

No. [This is clearly stated in the MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Procedure names must comply with the rules for identifiers and must be
>   unique within the schema.

Since you have a table with the same name, in that schema, you cannot create the stored procedure with that name.

Comment: To be fair, that statement would be slightly more clear if it ended with "unique across all objects in the schema." Currently it could be interpreted as unique within all procedures in the schema. IMHO.

Comment: Are you familiar with opening Connect items?

Comment: Connect? What's that? :-)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the rule is that "schema+name" must be unique - so you can have two tables of the same name even, as long as they are in different schemas. The default schema is set by your user properties, this is `dbo` more often than not so if you do not specify a schema your object called `object` is actually `dbo.object`.

This means you *can* have a procedure with the same name as a table as long as they are in different schemas: so you could have a table "dbo.thingy", a procedure "procs.thingy", a view "views.thingy", and so on, if you really want - but this really would not be recommended as it will cause significant confusion later on.

If you are not using (or even familiar with) schemas then the short answer is no. Object names within a schema must be unique, so if you only have the one (default) schema then object names must be unique full stop.

Answer (score 2):

You will get error as there **schema.object_name** has to be **unique** in the database.

Instead when you create an SP, then suffix it with **usp_SP_NAME**. Naming conventions should be followed and enforced (through triggers or [Policy based management](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2298/enforce-sql-server-database-naming-conventions-using-policy-based-management/)), so that you don't encounter such issues.

**e.g.** *(below is just a convention that I use, you can use a different convention as well)*

usp_SP_NAME ==> user stored procedure (usp) and then Stored Procedure Name.

or

`usp_sBuyers` ==> user stored procedure that does select (s) from Buyers table.

`usp_uBuyers` ==> user stored procedure that does updates (u) to Buyers table.

Comment: While I agree in general, and acknowledge that naming conventions are quite subjective, I do have a couple of issues with your suggested scheme: (1) I don't get the point of the `usp_` prefix. In what context will you be confused that this object is anything but a stored procedure? You can't `EXEC` tables, views, functions, etc. and you can't `SELECT` from a stored procedure. Now imaging you are looking for a stored procedure in a list that does a certain thing - would adding `LastName_` to every last name in the phone book help you find a person faster?

Comment: (2) I don't really like stuffing the verb (`s` or `u`) in front of the entity name. As above, if I am looking for stored procedures in an alphabetical list, I am probably looking for all the stored procedures involving `Buyers`, not all stored procedures that select or update stuff. With your scheme, they'll be grouped together by what they do at a high level, rather than what they do it to. I also see no need to be cryptic. How often are you typing a procedure name that typing out the word `SELECT` instead of just `s` is going to be painful? (3) My pref is `obj_verb` e.g. `dbo.Buyer_Update`.

Comment: These are just observations about your scheme and don't really relate to the question (except that their naming scheme - or rather, lack of one - has issues too).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good points, but just my way of naming them as we use it for our application. I was just giving an example as you said that naming conventions are subjective.